# Get Mule ESB to print list of fields

Tags: java, esb, mule

I'm having issues specifying fields coming from a POJO as a list to a collection splitter and then try and reference them in a logger.

I've tried

header:inbound:fieldname
message.payload.fieldname
payload:fieldname
payload.fieldname
etc
etc

Is there a way i can get mule to print me the list of available fields when it recieves a message so I can just look at the thing and copy the right one rather than guess?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Ah so a bit more investigation and I find to access fields in POJOs I need something like:
`#[ognl:fieldname]`

Its bloody cryptic this stuff.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mule 3.3.0 or better, use `#[message.payload.fieldname]`.